# assigning a Text box value to a constant variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, global-variables, userform, compile-time-constant

I want to assign a Constant global variable value dynamically from a user form input.This value will be used to declare the Typedef functions and other variables initially before running the actual Macro

my code looks like this

```
Const Imax

dim sys (0 to imax) as type computer.
```

I want the value for the Imax to be taken from the userform and retain that value constant
any suggestion or help please. Thank you so much for taking time to read my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Const** and make it **Public**, but it can only be "initialized" where it is declared.

**EDIT#1:**

For example:

```
Sub dural()
    Public Const Boltzmann = 1.3806488E-23
    a = b * Boltzmann
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply.is it possible to give an example for this? because i am new to vba

Comment: But i want to get the value from the userform and assign it to  the constant .how can i do that?

Comment: @ashvn I don't know how to that.